# @nrwl/nx + VS Code: Nx Console won't connect with project

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, nrwl-nx, nrwl

**Current behavior:** Nx Console won't connect with project.

**Expected behavior:** NX Console would connect with project and show options for generators, projects structure and commands.

My project structure:

[image: Nx project structure]

Broken Nx Console extension:

[image: Nx Console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was caused by old version of VS Code. After an update it works fine.

Comment: NOTE: pay attention to the new nrwl nx extension v.18.10.0. When used with vscode v.1.84 (October 2023) on MBP with M1 pro, it won't recognize the project anymore. Had to downgrade the vscode extension to 18.9.0. Hope to helped someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the Nx Console version to 12.x
[works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO27k.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).